# Loading a JSON file from the assets path in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am running a Rails 3 project on Heroku that syncs assets to an AWS bucket. In my javascript I am loading a JSON file with following call:

```
d3.json("<%= "#{asset_path "world.json"}" %>",
```

This works fine on localhost as world.json is in my assets path.

However, on deploy I get the error
*Origin http://foo.herokuapp.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.* 
coming back from AWS

I know why I am getting the error, just seeking a way around it on Heroku.

Comment: If you change your request from json to a standard ajax call with a dataType of jsonp, does it work?

Comment: unfortunately d3 doesn't work with jsonp

Comment: well I haven't used it, but have you tried this plugin? https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/jsonp